# Passing GET parameters to a popup with Open By Selector in Elementor (Wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, popup, elementor

I have a listing with different vimeo videos. Now I would like to place a simple link or button on each listing type. When pressing this button a popup should appear with the video player on it playing exactly this video from the listing.

everything works good so far. the only thing I cannot solve is to pass a GET parameter (vimeoid=1234) with "Open By Selector".

Listing Item:
has a normal text link to #vimeopopup. this works fine.
BUT if i try something like #vimeopopup?vimeoid=1234 this is not working.

Popup Item:
Has the Open By Selector a[href="#vimeopopup"]
Has the Request parameter "vimeoid" on a textelement at the moment just to show if i get the parameter.

Thanks for any help.

best,
Pascal

Comment: I think you should use data attributes, like `<a href="#vimeopopup" data-vimeo-id="1234">` this way you can retreive the video id from javascript and open the corresponding video in popup.

Comment: thank you GrafiCode. I just thought there must be a standard elementor way to pass a parameter or meta value to a popup using "Open By Selector". otherwise a popup is kind of blind and outside any context.